# Angular behaviour subject emiting

Tags: angular

I have trouble with BehaviourSubject in my service.
I have service witch get user location and put it into the `currentLocation` variable via `currentLocation.next({city: 'Some city...'})`

```
public currentLocation = new BehaviorSubject({}); //default value is empty object
```

In my component, I try to subscribe on `locationService.currentLocation` change and it works correctly, every change emit an event to my component

```
constructor() {
    this.locationService.currentLocation.subscribe(value => {      
        console.log('CHANGEDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD');
    });
}
```

But if I try to subscribe in another service (for example getting some data from the server according to `currentLocation`)
subscriptions called only once with `undefined` value. What I did wrong?

Comment: Does LocationService is injected in same module where other 2 components are injected?

Comment: @VivekJain sure!

Comment: please provide the code of that other service

Comment: @FaizalHussain another service just subscribe to changes and do console.log in the constructor (i edited original question)

Comment: Inject your service in the constructor.

Comment: @VivekJain @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'any'
})

Comment: `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})` try this

Comment: @VivekJain yes! it works!) thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all inject both of your service to root like this.

**LocationService**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LocationService {
  public currentLocation = new BehaviorSubject({});
}
```

**AnotherService**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
import { LocationService } from "./location.service";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AnotherService {
  constructor(private locationService: LocationService) {
    locationService.currentLocation.subscribe((val) => console.log('AnotherService: ',val));
  }
}
```

And your component should be look like below.

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { LocationService } from './location.service';
import { AnotherService } from './another.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(private locationService: LocationService, private anotherService: AnotherService) {
    locationService.currentLocation.subscribe((val) => console.log('App Component: ', val));
  }
}
```

See the working example in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vsfogc)

If you see above example you will find two output in console. One from component and another from Another Service.

Answer (score 1):

Please create a global service like this.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LocationService {
private subject = new Subject<any>();

setLocation(message) {
    this.subject.next(message);
}

clearMessage() {
    this.subject.next();
}

getLocation(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
}
```

}

You can set the location by calling setLocation function,

```
this.locationService.setLocation(locationObject)
```

Inject location service wherever u need and subscribe getLocation();

```
this.locationService.getLocation().subscribe(message => { 
 console.log(this.message) });
```